# What is the idea behind $\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal{A}]$ being $\mathcal{A}$-measurable

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales, expected-value

We have just introduced the notion of conditional expectations for sub-$\sigma$-algebras. Now let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{N}A_{n}=\Omega$ be a partition. Define $\mathcal{A}:=\sigma(\{A_{n}:n=1,...,N \})$ as the sub-$\sigma$-algebra.

I know that $\mathbb E[X\vert \mathcal{A}]=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\mathbb E[X\mid A_{n}]1_{A_{n}}$

But in a textbook, it is stated -without explanation- that $\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal{A}]$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable.

I do not understand what is meant by this. I mean are we talking about measurability in terms of functions or of sets? I am confused.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[X\mid\mathcal{A}]$ is a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so we can ask whether it induces a measurable function from $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ to $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. So it is the measurability of function.

Comment: @SangchulLee but we know that $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{F} $ so $\mathbb E[X \vert \mathcal{A}]$ is automatically $\mathcal{F}-$measurable, correct?

Comment: Yes. That is true.